# JavaScript / HTML work with DOM, Button which count click and make new string every time when I click

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frontend

I need create button which count click but make every time new string. I have that function with scope which make count every time when I click, but I cannot understand, why in HTML it every time count zero, should be like this:
(Verticaly every click make new string with updated count)
1
2
3
4
...

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="button" value="Count" onclick="add_count()">
</form>

function add_count() {
let integer = (function () {
    let counter = 0;
    return function() {return counter++;};
}());
let tag = document. createElement("p");
let text;
text = document. createTextNode(integer());
tag. appendChild(text);
let element = document. getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
element. appendChild(tag)};
```

Comment: Move `let integer = ...` outside the scope of `add_count` so it's not redefined every time you call `add_count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the `counter` initialization outside of the function scope

I've tweaked your code a bit.

Note: try not using inline event listeners, instead use event listeners in JavaScript file

```js
let counter = 0;

const button = document.querySelector('input');

function add_count() {
  let integer = (() =>  counter++);
  const tag = document.createElement("p");
  const text = document.createTextNode(integer());
  tag.appendChild(text);
  const element = document.body
  element.appendChild(tag)
};

button.addEventListener('click', add_count)
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="button" value="Count">
</form>
```

Comment: Its so obviously! Many thanks man!